# Does Greasemonkey publish every script present in its script directory?

Tags: upload, greasemonkey

I learned about the greasemonkey recently. I have written scripts to skip every login page I encounter by submitting the value of password in plain text. My doubt is that does greasemonkey uploads every script file present in its script directory and publishes it on userscripts.org. I was not able to get any clear information on this subject in their privacy options or on greasespot.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Greasemonkey does not automatically upload your scripts anywhere. To upload to userscripts.org, you must manually log in and upload yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.What is the procedure to use a script (or install it) from some disc location instead of using the default path "AppData/..."

Comment: AFAIK, you can install the script by simply navigating to it, and the greasemonkey extension should prompt you to install it - which then copies it to the normal AppData location you mention (I don't think it's possible to use a user script with FF/greasemonkey from an alternate location).